# How to get better exception information out of Android Studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Whilst running in the Android Studio debugger, I received the following (flutter/dart):

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
The getter 'year' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: year

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      _DateFormatPatternField.formatYear (package:intl/src/intl/date_format_field.dart:398:21)
#2      _DateFormatPatternField.formatField (package:intl/src/intl/date_format_field.dart:378:16)
#3      _DateFormatPatternField.format (package:intl/src/intl/date_format_field.dart:243:12)
#4      DateFormat.format (package:intl/src/intl/date_format.dart:298:26)
...
```

Usually the debugger is gracious enough to break at the error, or at least print a useful stack, but in this case this was the full extent of the message (including the final ellipsis!)

Is there a better way to get some hint out of the IDE as to where the offending method was called from in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way in Studio, but adding [catcher](https://pub.dev/packages/catcher) overrides the default flutter error handlers and provides a proper stack trace.

Bit of a sledgehammer to crack a nut, but oh well.